# C# charting simple connected objects

Tags: c#, charts

I'm looking to make what I believe is a simple chart to show connections between objects.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> ConnectedList { get; set; } = new List<MyClass>();

    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Connect(MyClass myClass)
    {
        ConnectedList.Add(myClass);
    }
}
```

If I have an instance of MyClass with name "A" which connects to "B" and "C", and "B" connects to "D" etc, etc. I'd like to chart these connections represented by simple lines and circles.

Anyone aware of a free library for this? Or an example of a better approach.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_chart.asp

Comment: https://canvasjs.com/asp-net-mvc-charts/

Comment: What type of app are you working on? Desktop/web/console? Please update a question with these details and please provide in what format you need a chart (just rendered image, like png?)

Comment: The idea is to show connected network devices to give a quick/easy high level view. Png would work.

Comment: Do you mean show a connected graph of objects? That's not what most people call a chart. In general, you need to track both the objects (or nodes) and connections (or edges)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: So your objects can be displayed as simple as a string? Who should do the layout? The user or some clever code? Or first an automated layout and then let the user interactively move the objects around? How many objects will there be? What kind of and how many connections?

Comment: There must be gazillions of network charting freeware, imo. If you want to roll one of your own, 200 lines of code will do to turn a MSChart into one with all my above ideas including png and xml save and load as well as editing text, connection etc..

Comment: @Flydog57 yes a graph not a chart. ( A ) --- ( B ) --- ( D ) etc

Comment: MSChart can do graphs as well. 200 lines of code: [MSChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abwoX.gif)

Comment: @TaW that looks promising, I downloaded MSChart sample graphs but I don't see any examples like that gif you posted. Where is that from?

Comment: I wrote it to see if it would indeed work as I imagined. It pretty much does. It uses Annotations (Rectangle, Ellipse and Line) only. As any chart it scales when resized and the xml save/load is a nice bonus..A current limitaton is that is supports only one text with one font and that the lines won't support any arrows easily. Linestyles would be easy..